# Regular Expressions firstname.middlename.lastname split and delete middlename and "."

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox

I am looking for a Regex that will split a firstname.middlename.lastname into:

First Middle Last

But then deletes the entire middle name (including the periods between the first and last name)

I am passing this to a textbox to display the firstname lastname to the user.

If it makes any difference I am using winforms for this.

---

Thanks to the quick action of some kind people on this forum here is the answer to my solution!:

```
        string strName =  Environment.UserName.ToString();
        strName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(strName.ToLower());

        String shortName = Regex.Replace(strName, @"[.]\w*[.]", " ");

        uxCreator.SelectedText = shortName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there's some pressing reason to use Regex I'd go for the more simple:

```
String fullName = "Harry.Bob.McGraw";
String[] names = fullName.Split('.');
String shortName = String.Format("{0} {1}", names[0], names[2]);
```

This gives you the shortened name in shortName.

Also, if you really must have Regex, then you could use

```
String fullName = "Harry.Bob.McGraw";
String shortName = Regex.Replace(fullName, @"[.]\w*[.]", " ");
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the \w* does in the regex.replace statement?

Comment: The `\w` is a Regex character symbolizing any word character - essentially a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _. I find this [Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) to be frequently invaluable. EDIT - the * means "0 or more", so when applied after the `\w` it means 0 or more word characters.

Answer (score 1):

How about something very simple (without the split)?

```
string input = "Harry.Bob.McGraw";
string pattern = @"(?<=\w+)\.\w+\.(?=\w+)";

var result = Regex.Replace( input, pattern, " " );

// result = "Harry McGraw"
```

You can use the same expression for splitting:

```
var result = Regex.Split( input, pattern );

// result[0] = "Harry"
// result[1] = "McGraw"
```

*Note: The regex is fundamentally no different from Matrin's. I've included the zero-width assertions (aka lookarounds) in case you want to apply this to a larger body of text.*

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly!. Thank you for such a quick response. Also, I did not know I had put tags in the title name. Haha. thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a RegEx. It's easier to use the string manipulation functions:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4398/string-manipulation-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for the option! I just had a small thing to mess with so I didn't see a huge issue using regex functions for it. I could see using the string manipulation functions for long complex things though. Thanks again!